# How to convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

**Table values**:

```
EMP_NO EMP_NAME                     
-------------- 
    14 admin                          
     1 ram                            
     2 mohan                          
     3 mallu                          
     4 scoot                          
     5 jim                            
     6 ravi                           
     7 manju                          
     8 manoj                          
     9 sarath                         
    10 hemanth
```

how to convert rows to columns?

Comment: you want in sql or oracle?

Comment: @armunin its not duplicate of that post as user asking for pivot

Comment: @Terror.Blade see tags

Comment: @ram sql and oracle has different ways to pivot thats why i asked. anyways i provide oracle solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following query for oracle

```
select 
   emp_no,
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, emp_name || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') enames
from 
   emp
group by 
   emp_no
;
```

for sql server try

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       emp_name 
    FROM tblemployee
) as s
PIVOT
(
    min(emp_id)
    FOR emp_id
)AS pivot
```

Comment: how to use PIVOT for this case?

Comment: As far as I know there is a `PIVOT`-function in Oracle as well. Maybe [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) helps.

Comment: @Armunin in ur reference link there **PIVOT  (SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity FOR (product_code) IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c));** how to is SUM for my case?

Comment: I haven't worked with `PIVOT` so far, just wanted to give some more information

Comment: +1 for me and armunin too :)